# The print options and default settings in PHP Excel isn't working in DOMPDF

Tags: php, phpexcel, dompdf

The Excel file that i made is like this:[image]

the print option in my php excel is

```
$activeSheet->getPageSetup()->setOrientation(
    PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    ->setFitToWidth(1)
    ->setFitToHeight(0);
```

and the default setting is

```
$sheet->getDefaultStyle()->getAlignment()->setVertical(
    PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_TOP);
$sheet->getDefaultStyle()->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(
                PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_LEFT);
$sheet->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setName('Arial');
$sheet->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setSize(12);
```

the PDF output as you can see below is different
[image]

Why the pdf file not using the print options and default setting i made above?

Answer (score 1):

No they don't.... print settings like fit to height and fit to width are MS Excel specific settings, and the only print settings whose function is replicated when generating a PDF are the paper size and orientation

Comment: so how can i make the pdf file looks like the excel file?

Comment: Take a look at how the PDF writer works, and see how you can apply the fittoheight() and fittowidth() with the code

Comment: Unfortunately dompdf does not support any type of "fit" settings for rendering HTML. The best option for ensuring fit is to use percent. I don't really know how that works when exporting from XLS using PHP Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Just a reminder for anyone else finding this question, `->setFitToHeight(0);` can not be 0. Your effectively saying fit to one page width and no page height. Minimum is 1. If you go to Excel and look at the page setup, it will not let you fit to 0 pages. So fit to one page width and one page height minimum.

```
$activeSheet->getPageSetup()->setOrientation(
PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
->setFitToWidth(1)
->setFitToHeight(1);
```